# Simple Lightbox HTML

Tags: lightbox

I'm using WP All Import to maintain 3000 separate posts. The template is HTML-based. I've found that the Simple Lightbox plugin works if I set up my template html like so:

```
<a href="https://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/{imagefilename[1]}" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="36"><img src="https://sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/{imagefilename[1]}" alt="" /></a>
```

I'm missing at least one bit of code, though. The not-unique asset number (?)...

```
 data-slb-asset="842492188"
```

Can I get away with not including it? Am I missing anything else important?

Comment: You will need to ask in the Simple Lightbox plugin's support channels!

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.